# Set php-fpm default configuration file location

Tags: php

I've built from source php + php-fpm + nginx few times.

I'm used to keep everything inside `/usr/local`

Hovewer php-fpm config file `php-fpm.conf` is always loaded from `/etc/`

Of course I can change the location with the `-y` directive when php-fpm is started but I'd prefer to have a different location by default.

Is there any way to do this?

Does the default location depends upon a directive set when running `./config` before the actual build?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performing a multi-file search on PHP's sources and build files reveals that

`php-fpm.conf` location is determined by the compile-time option

```
--sysconfdir=/path/to
```

specified when invoking `./configure`

Comment: How can I check where the php-fpm is searching for the .conf file at runtime? I'm not seeing it in `php -i`.

Comment: @Blossoming_Flower You should see the directive path option after `Configure Command =>` when you invoke `php -i`. If it's not there it should be in the default location. Post your comment as a question (and write here a commend you did that) so I can give you a more detailed answer (and others may contribute).

Answer (score 0):

actually the real reason is you used the old TARed php source code,
you should RM the old TARed php source one and re-Tar xvf php-version.tar.gz,
lastly, configure it and so on. you can try it if you don't believe it~

:p

Answer (score -1):

- You can compile php with the `--with-config-file-path=PATH` compile-time option.

  For your reference [PHP Compile-Time Options](http://php.net/manual/en/configure.about.php)
- You can use a custom php.ini file using a `.htaccess` with Apache adding le line

  `SetEnv PHPRC /location/todir/containing/phpinifile`
- [To specify a custom php.ini with NginX check this link](https://serverfault.com/questions/667160/how-can-i-specify-which-php-ini-file-to-use-in-my-nginx-conf-file)
- As you pointed out you can use a CLI directive to choose a different `php.ini` as well

Comment: `--with-config-file-path=PATH` sets the location of `php.ini`, not the location of `php-fpm.conf`