# php-fpm can't work within tengine on centos 6

Tags: php, nginx

I have been installed **php-fpm** and **tengine** **centos 6**.

Here is my */usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf*

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;

    error_page  404              /404.html;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           html;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
    #   fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME/$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    #
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny  all;
    }
}
```

http://172.104.126.251/index.html Work!

But

http://172.104.126.251/index.php can't work, it appear error page.

Hope you guys can help me, thanks!

Comment: do you have already running on `127.0.0.1:9000` php-fpm? You are routing php there, so, if you have no php-fpm module running, no reply will be sent.

Comment: I type the command "service php-fpm start", it shows ok. But I type "netstat -tclpn" can't find 127.0.0.1:9000 listen.

Comment: then try to check php-fpm config file and adjust it to be running where you like. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35668008/5476782). Also there is [this](https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2011/nginx-and-php-fpm-configuration-and-optimizing-tips-and-tricks/) nginx article for php-fpm configuration.

Comment: fastcgi_pass    unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;

Comment: Finally,I solve the problem.
http://172.104.126.251/index.php  it works.
I am not through "9000 port" to start php-fpm, instead I through "php-cgi.sock". 
Thanks to Karlos.

Comment: It works. I just use sock not port. Here are my config.

location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
        #    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
        #    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /$document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/tmp/php-cgi.sock;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_param  PHP_VALUE  "open_basedir=$document_root:/tmp/";
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }