# where is php-fpm getting its config values on osx

Tags: php, macos, homebrew, fpm

I'm trying to php-fpm on my osx by running:

```
php-fpm -t
```

and I get this error:

```
[30-Dec-2017 13:36:12] ERROR: failed to open error_log (/usr/var/log/php-fpm.log): No such file or directory (2)
[30-Dec-2017 13:36:12] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[30-Dec-2017 13:36:12] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
```

i don't have that file nor can I create it - even when using sudo:

```
$:/usr $ sudo mkdir var
Password:
mkdir: var: Operation not permitted
```

so my next big move is to find where exactly is this log file directory setup in php-fpm configuration (so that i can [decide](https://github.com/rlerdorf/php7dev/issues/48) where the log file should go).. there seems to be many configuration files, so I refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35669139/766570) in finding the location of my php-fpm configuration file. so in the output of my `php -i` file I have this:

```
'--sysconfdir=/usr/local/etc/php/7.1'
```

and there I have the following files:

## php-fpm.conf

```
// can't be coming from this file
// b/c this is telling me it's /usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log

; If it's set to "syslog", log is sent to syslogd instead of being written
; into a local file.
; Note: the default prefix is /usr/local/var
; Default Value: log/php-fpm.log
```

so where is it coming from?

also when I run this:

```
which php-fpm
/usr/sbin/php-fpm
```

note sure if it helps

Comment: What does the output of `php-fpm -i` say? (Note: not `php -i`)

Comment: @MattGibson [it](https://gist.github.com/abbood/dc99b6a2838be6a91b782250d2285896) says `'--sysconfdir=/private/etc'`.. lemme take it from here

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`php-fpm.conf` location is determined by the option

```
--sysconfdir=/path/to
```

specified when invoking `$ ./confugure` just before compiling php-fpm.

Usually it is `/etc` but may be different in your case.

Invoking `$ php-fpm -i` will show the options passed to `configure`.

Just look after `Configure Command =>`.

From the comments I see you have found `'--sysconfdir=/private/etc'` so I would look right there.

---

Note that you can invoke php-fpm specifying a different location for the configuration file using the `-y` option.

Answer (score 2):

Because you mentioned local you must be using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) and so the php-fpm config file is at:

`/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.conf`

And the www pool config is at:

`/usr/local/etc/php/7.4/php-fpm.d/www.conf`

Note the path version number will change in the future.

You can put your own configs in the same folder as www.conf (they must end in .conf to be included). E.g. I added one that had `listen = /usr/local/var/run/php-fpm.my-username.sock` which I learned [here](http://blog.koenreiniers.nl/guide-to-combining-apache-virtual-hosts-and-php7-fpm/) so I could use a socket instead of a port for my Site virtual server.

I found these other commands useful:

To view the logs:

`tail -f /usr/local/var/log/php-fpm.log`

To check the user fpm was launched as:

`ps aux | egrep 'php'`

And be sure to start the brew service with sudo and if you accidentally start one without sudo be sure to stop it:

`sudo brew services start php`

Comment: After hours of frustration, this answer was exactly what I needed! I had a lot of difficulty tracking down a solution for Mac/Homebrew. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Up to MAC OS Catalina this one-liner works:

`lsof -Pni4 | grep LISTEN | grep php`

Output:

```
php-fpm   93649 asrar    9u  IPv4 0xd7c340d64c780f97      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9073 (LISTEN)

php-fpm   94392 asrar    9u  IPv4 0xd7c340d64c780f97      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9073 (LISTEN)

php-fpm   94393 asrar    9u  IPv4 0xd7c340d64c780f97      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9073 (LISTEN)
```