# PHP-FPM not running on Nginx under OS X Mojave

Tags: php, nginx, macos-mojave

I upgraded from *Sierra* on my Mac to Mojave and when upgraded and installed the php-fpm (php), nginx and wrote in a new config.

The PHP is not parsing the php code, I can see on the header that it's running PHP and even the logs shows it. But, when it renders the page, it's blank. No useful log as well.

> curl -v localhost.test/info.php
>   *   Trying 127.0.0.1...
>   * TCP_NODELAY set
>   * Connected to localhost.test (127.0.0.1) port 80 (#0)
>
> > GET /info.php HTTP/1.1
> >     Host: localhost.test
> >     User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> >     Accept: */*
> >      < HTTP/1.1 200 OK < Server: nginx/1.15.8 < Date: Mon, 11 Feb 2019 07:37:17 GMT < Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 <
> >     Transfer-Encoding: chunked < Connection: keep-alive < X-Powered-By:
> >     PHP/7.3.1 < 
> >     * Connection #0 to host localhost.test left intact

```
[11-Feb-2019 15:21:30] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[11-Feb-2019 15:21:30] NOTICE: [pool www] 'user' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[11-Feb-2019 15:21:30] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[11-Feb-2019 15:21:30] NOTICE: [pool www] 'group' directive is ignored when FPM is not running as root
[11-Feb-2019 15:21:30] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 22336
[11-Feb-2019 15:21:30] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

And currently got the following (all installed via Homebrew).

1. PHP 7.3.1
2. NGINX 1.15.8

> /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    include servers/*;
}
```

> /usr/local/etc/nginx/servers/localhost.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost.test;
    access_log  /usr/local/var/log/nginx/localhost.test.access.log;

    index index.php;

    root /Users/louie/Development/php;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include        fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    }
}
```

What could be the cause why this it's not parsing the PHP code?

Comment: You can check if PHP-FPM is running here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64673174/9185662

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the ~.php is correct.

```
# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include        /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

Also related to [nginx showing blank PHP pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15423500/nginx-showing-blank-php-pages)

Answer (score 0):

If the page is blank, there's most likely an error in the PHP.  Replace the PHP page with something simple that outputs the current configuration:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

If that works, you know the problem is with your PHP.

Comment: Thanks. I missed the include params and the rest of the fastcgi_param options on the config. After I revised it and doubled check, restarted. It works now.

Comment: @LouieMiranda Glad it works!  You should post that as the answer to your question and mark it as the answer to help anyone else who runs into this issue.